# most tfm fonts are not found

Tags: fonts, plain-tex, metafont

I had the same problem with texlive 2020 and did a full installation of texlive 2021:

```
\font\tenrm=mdugmm7y at 10pt 
\tenrm
Hello World!
\bye
```

doesn't work with tex, pdftex, xetex or luatex. All of them complain that they cant access the font. And this happens for almost every font. Even when I put mdugmm7y.tfm and mdugmm7y.vf in the same directory it doesn't work.
The error from xetex is:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...
```

Tex creates a dvi but there a just random symbols and no actual text.

Using truetype or openttype fonts with fontspec in latex works fine. I only have these problems with the tfm fonts.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't replicate your issue.

Comment: @egreg Mmh, thats weird, I did a full reinstallation of tex live 2021 to make sure that this issue wasn't caused by the texlive version my distribution ships (slackware). There were also no issues during the installation... So which texlive version do you use?

Comment: On Linux boxes I always install the Tug TeX Live https://tug.org/texlive

Comment: I'm using the same tex distribution. I have the same problem on mint and when installing it via guix. So did you run your test on Linux as well? If so please tell me which distribution you were using.

Comment: type -a xdvipdfmx
xdvipdfmx is /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/xdvipdfmx
xdvipdfmx is /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/xdvipdfmx
xdvipdfmx is /usr/bin/xdvipdfmx

Comment: which xdvipdfmx
/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/xdvipdfmx

Comment: I get the same error but why use 8bit fonts with xetex (all hyphenation of words using non ascii letters will be wrong)

Comment: @egreg I don't have this font, you've got URW Garamond from somewhere?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle From `kpsewhich mdugmm7y.tfm` I get `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/mathdesign/mdugm/mdugmm7y.tfm`. Tested with `tex`, `pdftex`, `xetex` and `luatex` and it always works.

Comment: @egreg yes I have that (and actually it works in pdflatex so I guess there is a map file missing?) with xetex --no-pdf followed by xdvipdfmx the vf file points to a missing file:  `$ xdvipdfmx aa803.xdv
aa803.xdv -> aa803.pdf
[1
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ugmm8a
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ugmm8a.
mktexpk: perhaps ugmm8a is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

xdvipdfmx:warning: Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "md-gmm8y".
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Aha! That's the problem! `ugmm8a` must be installed with `getnonfreefonts`

Comment: @egreg, thanks for confirming. I suspected `getnonfeefonts` was involved:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can often get better error messages for font related issues from xetex by running `xdvipdfmx` by hand (after `xetex --no-pdf`) as unfortunately the automatic call to `xdvipdfmx` suppresses error messages.

You get no error from xetex as the tfm file for the font is in texlive

```
$ xetex --no-pdf aa803
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xetex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./aa803.tex [1] )
Output written on aa803.xdv (1 page, 248 bytes).
Transcript written on aa803.log.
```

But runing the dvi driver you get

```
$ xdvipdfmx aa803.xdv
aa803.xdv -> aa803.pdf
[1
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ugmm8a
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ugmm8a.
mktexpk: perhaps ugmm8a is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

xdvipdfmx:warning: Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "md-gmm8y".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> This font is mapped to a physical font "ugmm8a".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please check if kpathsea library can find this font: ugmm8a
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

No output PDF file written.
```

as the tfm file is referencing a virtual font but the actual font (corresponding to URW Garamond) is not in texlive by default.

You can install the missing files with `getnonfreefonts` as documented here

https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Note that using 8-bit legacy fonts with xetex is not recommended, no hyphenation patterns for these encodings are loaded into the default format. This doesn't make much difference if you are writing English with no accented letters but becomes important in many languages.

Comment: `xetex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv"` avoids the double call.

Comment: @egreg yes I know but somehow it seems more complicated to pass in the driver options nested as an option to xetex and in fact I never do it that way: I always revert to my roots and do it in two steps if I need to see what xdvipdfmx is doing.

Comment: The `7y` part means that the font is suitable for an OMS encoded font, so there is no hyphenation problem.

Comment: @egreg yes (although it's being used for text here) but the real document may have more than one font loaded so this seemed worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

The mystery can be explained. If I do

```
vftovp mdugmm7y
```

I get

```
[...]
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME md-gmm7y)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 23602320625)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 9.962616)
   )
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME md-gmm8y)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 32734444133)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
[...]
(CHARACTER O 170
   (CHARWD R 0.498)
   (CHARHT R 0.707)
   (CHARDP R 0.238)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR O 247)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 171
   (CHARWD R 0.498)
   (CHARHT R 0.6875)
   (CHARDP R 0.238)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR O 206)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 172
   (CHARWD R 0.498)
   (CHARHT R 0.707)
   (CHARDP R 0.183)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR O 207)
      )
   )
[...]
```

The `md-gmm8y` font is mapped to `ugmm8a.pfb` both with `pdftex` and `xetex`, but the former only loads PFB files that are actually required in the PDF, whereas `xdvipdfmx` wants to access them as soon as they're referenced. By the way, the characters taken from `md-gmm8y` are `§ † ‡ ¶`.

Now, lo and behold, `ugmm8a.pfb` is only available if you install `garamond` with [`getnonfreefonts`](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) (which I have done in my macOS box). If I try the sample file on a Fedora box with no `getnonfreefonts` action, then `pdftex` is happy, *unless* I also ask for `\char'170`, when I get

```
!pdfTeX error: pdftex (file ugmm8a.pfb): cannot open Type1 font file for reading
```

After installing `getnonfreefonts` and doing (with superuser privileges)

```bash
getnonfreefonts --sys garamond
```

all goes well.

What's the possible explanation? When `mathdesign` was being developed, the URW Garamond fonts used to be available in TeX Live; they were later withdrawn for licensing reasons. The involved glyphs are added in the virtual fonts in order to make the font to provide a complete font in the OMS encoding. The difference in behavior between `pdftex` and `xetex` about PFB loading has never been noticed before, possibly because nobody tried to use `mathdesign` Garamond with XeLaTeX.